# How to use dropdown for data selection in Python and Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have grouped data with more than 2 groups. I then plot it with a grouped barchart using plotly for a specific set of 2 groups. How can I create 2 dropdown menus that select which group to be plotted as trace1 and which group as trace2?

The example below uses hardcoded groups 1 for trace1 and group 2 for trace2. I would like to control these with the dropdown menus.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

d = {'x': ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'], 'y': [1,2,3,10,20,30,100,200,300], 'group': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df[df['group']==1].y,
    name='trace1'
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df[df['group']==2].y,
    name='trace2'
)
data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='group'
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.offline.plot(fig, filename='grouped-bar')
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems like a good place to start: https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/

Comment: I have tried the examples but they show more complex cases with restyling or changing the plot type. It is difficult for me to extract a simpler functionality of just selecting which data to be plotted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following suggestion should let you do exactly what you're looking for.
Just select the source of the traces using the two dropdown menus:

**Plot 1 - Selection is group 1 vs group 1:**

[image]

**Plot 2 - Selection is group 2 vs group 3:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# Imports
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
d = {'x': ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'], 'y': [1,2,3,10,20,30,100,200,300], 'group': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# split df by groups and organize them in a dict
groups = df['group'].unique().tolist()
dfs={}
for g in groups:
    dfs[str(g)]=df[df['group']==g]

# get column names from first dataframe in the dict
#colNames = list(dfs[list(dfs.keys())[0]].columns)
#colNames=colNames[:2]


# one trace for each column per dataframe
fig=go.Figure()

# set up the first trace
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=dfs['1']['x'],
                             y=dfs['1']['y'],
                             visible=True)
             )
# set up the second trace
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=dfs['1']['x'],
                             y=dfs['1']['y'],)
             )

#f=fig.to_dict()

# plotly start
# buttons for menu 1, names
updatemenu=[]
buttons=[]

# button with one option for each dataframe
for df in dfs.keys():
    #print(b, df)
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=df,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[dfs[str(df)]['y'].values],
                               'type':'bar'}, [0]],
                        )
                  )

# another button with one option for each dataframe
buttons2=[]
for df in dfs.keys():
    buttons2.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=df,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[dfs[str(df)]['y'].values],
                               'type':'bar'}, [1]],
                        )
                  )

# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenu=[]
your_menu=dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)
your_menu2=dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu2)
#updatemenu[1]
updatemenu[0]['buttons']=buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction']='down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive']=True
updatemenu[1]['buttons']=buttons2
updatemenu[1]['y']=0.5

# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)

# add notations to the dropdown menus
fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        go.layout.Annotation(text="<b>group/<br>trace:</b>",
                             x=-0.15, xref="paper",
                             y=1.15, yref="paper",
                             align="left", showarrow=False),
        go.layout.Annotation(text="<b>group/<br>trace:</b>",
                             x=-0.15, xref="paper", y=0.6,
                             yref="paper", showarrow=False),
                  ]
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: @Konstantin Thank you for accepting my suggestion. This answer would not have been possible without the effort from user nicolaskruchten on the answer to the question: [How to update one specific trace using updatemenus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077118/plotly-how-to-update-one-specific-trace-using-updatemenus/59077581?noredirect=1#comment104398398_59077581)

I'd also suggest you take a look at [How do the buttons for the update menus really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070876/plotly-how-do-the-buttons-for-the-update-menus-really-work)