# interactive PCA with dropdown menu for the both axis with Plotly python

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, plotly-python, plotly-express

I'm trying to create an interactive PCA plot using plotly-express and graph objects in python (go.Scatter).

The plot should have 2 dropdowns menus (for x-axis and y-axis) to change between the first 5 PCA in the data.

Each data point also belongs to a treatment group either Before, After, or QC.

I was able to plot the PCA1 and PCA2 with plotly-express package but when trying to add the 2 dropdown menus that will update the plot between the 5 PCA it become a mess.

The example data is in my [GitHub link](https://github.com/TalWac/stakoverflow-Qustion/blob/main/components_df.csv),the first 5 columns are the first 5 PCAs.

The code the generate PC1 vs PC2 is:

```
labels={'0': 'PC 1 (22.0%)',
 '1': 'PC 2 (19.6%)',
 '2': 'PC 3 (11.1%)',
 '3': 'PC 4 (8.2%)',
 '4': 'PC 5 (3.9%)',
 'color': 'Group'}

fig1 = px.scatter(components_df, x=0 , y=2 ,
                  color = 'Class',
                  width=1000, height=700,
                 template='presentation',
                 labels=labels, 
                 title="PCA Score Plot (PC{} vs. PC{})".format(1, 2) ,
                 hover_data=['idx', 'SampleID']
                )
fig1.show()
```

and it looks like this :
[image]

I'm trying to add 2 dropdown menus like I draw above to update the x-axis and the y-axis with the different PC's.

So first step was to add_trace on the figure to add other PCs to the figure but dont know how to add graph object to plotly-express to that what  i did:

```
fig = go.Figure()
for Class, group in components_df.groupby("Class"):
#     print(group[0])
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=group[0], y=group[1], name=Class, mode='markers', 
      hovertemplate="Class=%s<br>PC1=%%{x}<br>PC2=%%{y}<extra></extra>"% Class))    

for Class, group in components_df.groupby("Class"):
#     print(group[0])
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=group[0], y=group[2], name=Class, mode='markers', 
      hovertemplate="Class=%s<br>PC1=%%{x}<br>PC3=%%{y}<extra></extra>"% Class))  

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(
        active=0,
        buttons=list(
            [dict(label = 'All',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [True, True, True, True,True]},
                          {'title': 'All',
                           'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'PC1 PC1',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [True, False, False, False, False]}, # the index of True aligns with the indices of plot traces
                          {'title': 'PC1 PC1',
                           'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'PC1 PC2',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [False, True, False, False, False]},
                          {'title': 'AAPL',
                           'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'PC1 PC3',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [False, False, True, False, False]},
                          {'title': 'AMZN',
                           'showlegend':True}]),
            ])
        )
    ])
```

and that  is the result:

[image]

There are many problems with that:

1. when changing the different options in the dropdown menu also the legends change (they suppose the stay fixed)
2. when changing the different options in the dropdown menu it does not lools like the data should be
3. it does not look nice like in the plotly-express.
4. there is only one dropdown

The code is base on many explanations in the documentation and blogs:

1. [How to change plot data using dropdowns](https://www.kaggle.com/jrmistry/plotly-how-to-change-plot-data-using-dropdowns)
2. [Dropdown Menus in Python](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/)
3. [Adding interactive filters](https://docs.datapane.com/tutorials-and-guides/interactive-filters)
4. [Setting the Font, Title, Legend Entries, and Axis Titles in Python](https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/)

Any hint will be appreciated on how to add correct add_trac or correct dropdown menu

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

- it's all about being highly structured and systematic. **Plotly Express** does generate a decent base chart. Use `fig1.to_dict()` to view **graph object** structures it has built
- challenge I found with adding **updatemenus** to **Plotly Express** figure - it's a multi-trace figure with trace defining marker color.  This can be simplified to a single trace figure with an array defining marker color
- then it's a case of building **updatemenus**. This I have done as nested list comprehensions. Outer loop axis (each menu), inner loop principle component (each menu item)

**Updates**

- *magic colors - fair critique. I had used a hard coded **dict** for color mapping.  Now programmatically build `cmap` Reverted back to static definition of `cmap` as **dict** comprehension is not wanted.*  Changed to a **pandas** approach to building `cmap` with **lambda** function
- `"y": 1 if ax == "x" else 0.9` We are building two drop downs, one for *xaxis* and one for *yaxis*. Hopefully it's obvious that the positions of these menus needs to be different.  See docs: https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/ For similar reason **active** property s being set.  Make sure drop downs show what is actually plotted in the figure
- **legend** refer back to point I made about multi-trace figures.  Increases complexity!  Have to use synthetic traces and this technique [Plotly: How to update one specific trace using updatemenus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077118/plotly-how-to-update-one-specific-trace-using-updatemenus)

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

components_df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TalWac/stakoverflow-Qustion/main/components_df.csv"
)

labels = {
    "0": "PC 1 (22.0%)",
    "1": "PC 2 (19.6%)",
    "2": "PC 3 (11.1%)",
    "3": "PC 4 (8.2%)",
    "4": "PC 5 (3.9%)",
    "color": "Group",
}

# cmap = {
#     cl: px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[i]
#     for i, cl in enumerate(
#         components_df.groupby("Class", as_index=False).first()["Class"]
#     )
# }
# revert back to static dictionary as dynamic building is not wanted
# cmap = {'After': '#636EFA', 'Before': '#EF553B', 'QC': '#00CC96'}
# use lambda functions instead of dict comprehension
df_c = components_df.groupby("Class", as_index=False).first()
df_c["color"] = df_c.apply(lambda r: px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[r.name], axis=1)
cmap = df_c.set_index("Class").loc[:,"color"].to_dict()

fig1 = go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(
        x=components_df["0"],
        y=components_df["1"],
        customdata=components_df.loc[:, ["idx", "SampleID", "Class"]],
        marker_color=components_df["Class"].map(cmap),
        mode="markers",
        hovertemplate="Class=%{customdata[2]}<br>x=%{x}<br>y=%{y}<br>idx=%{customdata[0]}<br>SampleID=%{customdata[1]}<extra></extra>",
    )
).update_layout(
    template="presentation",
    xaxis_title_text=labels["0"],
    yaxis_title_text=labels["1"],
    height=700,
)

fig1.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "active": 0 if ax == "x" else 1,
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": f"{ax}-PCA{pca+1}",
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {ax: [components_df[str(pca)]]},
                        {f"{ax}axis": {"title": {"text": labels[str(pca)]}}},
                        [0],
                    ],
                }
                for pca in range(5)
            ],
            "y": 1 if ax == "x" else 0.9,
        }
        for ax in ["x", "y"]
    ]
).update_traces(showlegend=False)

# add a legend by using synthetic traces.  NB, this will leave markers at 0,0
fig1.add_traces(
    px.scatter(
        components_df.groupby("Class", as_index=False).first(),
        x="0",
        y="1",
        color="Class",
        color_discrete_map=cmap,
    )
    .update_traces(x=[0], y=[0])
    .data
)
```

[image]

Comment: -Thank you very much for your time, it looks really amazing!  with your permission I would like to ask 1). if it is possible to add a legend explaining which color represents each group like in my first plot upper-right side *Class*.  2).  how did you know how to select the colors #1F77B4, #FF7F0E, #2CA02C to fit the template="presentation" colors, in cases I have more than 3 groups (Before, After, and QC). 3). in the code the line :"y": 1 if ax == "x" else 0.9, what it does, I tried to change the 1 and the 0.9 to different numbers and it changed the location of the dropdown menu. Many thanks!

Comment: @ Rob Raymond - Thank you very much for the elaborate explantion! In the creation of cmap dictionary there is a for loop with enumerating but above it I did not understand what is the object in the first row- `cl: px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[i]`. it's not a lambda expression, nor list comprehension, right?

Comment: @ Rob Raymond- the dict comprehension (which is new to me) and the lambda expression are great solutions for me, Thank you! I'd like to ask you what complexity is the legend adds?  and a second question about lambda expression, the object  - `[r.name]`. `r`  is when you run through the color in `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly`, right? but what is `name`? I could not figure this out. And must say I have been learning **a lot** from your coding, Thank you very much

Comment: @TaL have you had the opportunity to define the none functional constraints of this solution?   I'd like to complete this answer or remove it if it cannot meet all constraints you need to apply to solution

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term>"none functional constraints of this solution"  so I do not know how to answer the question. The solution you provided is very good for me, and I appreciate your help, Thank you very much

Comment: ah ok - standard term in software engineering.  functional requirements are what it functionally needs to do (create a graph with selectors for x & y axis).  none functional are constraints on how, eg finishes in < 2s, uses < 10mb of RAM, coded in python and uses x,y,z libraries, does not use certain features of python etc, etc

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This graph is part of a larger report to be sent by mail as an HTML file, so I can not think of any non-functional constraints besides the size limit to be fit email. As for me, the solution is complete. Thank you very much